# Does TIR obeys laws of reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

After reaching the critical angle, do Snell's laws and laws of reflection hold good?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Snell's law of reflection holds. Also the Fresnel expressions hold, even if there is extinction so that the refractive index is complex valued.

Answer (score 0):

Well Snell's law of refraction gives the value of the sine of the angle of refraction>1. The sine of any angle cannot be greater than 1.
So , even if one say it can hold, it will not give any value that can be further worked upon. So instead light gets reflected, and yes the basic law of reflection hold.